# Neutron+VLAN. Allow a trunk traffic between VMs

Tags: networking, openstack, openstack-neutron, vlan, trunk

Please tell me, how can I make it possible to transfer Trunk traffic at the user level in the Neutron Private Network?

Description

We have the following private, non-shared network without any Gateway:

[image]

I want to make sure that VMs can configure Trunk-VLAN connections to each other. At the same time, the creation of these connections was controlled at the OS level (the count of such connections and VMs is completely chaotic and random )

[image]

The problem is the following - if you make several VMs on, for example, Centos and try to set up the relationship of one VM to another through the Trunk port with ID, for example, 5, the Neutron network completely drop such traffic.

```
### Both VMs ###

[root@vlan-X centos]# modprobe bonding
[root@vlan-X centos]# modprobe 8021q
[root@vlan-X centos]# echo "8021q" > /etc/modules-load.d/8021q.conf
[root@vlan-X centos]# echo "bonding" > /etc/modules-load.d/bonding.conf

### VM1 ###

[root@vlan-1 centos]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
NAME="eth1"
DEVICE="eth1"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="none"

[root@vlan-1 centos]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1.5
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=yes
DEVICE=eth1.5
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.10.15
PREFIX=24

[root@vlan-1 centos]# systemctl restart network

### VM2 ###

[root@vlan-2 centos]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
NAME="eth1"
DEVICE="eth1"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="none"

[root@vlan-2 centos]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1.5
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=yes
DEVICE=eth1.5
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.10.16
PREFIX=24

[root@vlan-2 centos]# systemctl restart network
[root@vlan-2 centos]# ping 192.168.10.15
PING 192.168.10.15 (192.168.10.15) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.10.16 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.16 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.16 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.16 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.16 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.16 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.16 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.16 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.10.15 ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 0 received, +8 errors, 100% packet loss, time 10001ms
pipe 4
```

At the same time, tcpdump looks like this - that is, VLAN was successfully accepted, but then even ARP is unsuccessful

```
[root@vlan-2 centos]# tcpdump -e -nvvvti eth1
tcpdump: listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
fa:16:3e:8f:7f:df > Broadcast, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 46: vlan 5, p 0, ethertype ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.10.15 tell 192.168.10.16, length 28
fa:16:3e:8f:7f:df > Broadcast, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 46: vlan 5, p 0, ethertype ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.10.15 tell 192.168.10.16, length 28
fa:16:3e:8f:7f:df > Broadcast, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 46: vlan 5, p 0, ethertype ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.10.15 tell 192.168.10.16, length 28
fa:16:3e:8f:7f:df > Broadcast, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 46: vlan 5, p 0, ethertype ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.10.15 tell 192.168.10.16, length 28
^C
4 packets captured
4 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

At the same time, the same design on VirtualBox with an internal network works fine.

What I have tried to solve this problem:

- I tried creating a network with option "--transparent-vlan" - nothing changed
- I tried creating a network with option "--transparent-vlan --disable-port-security" - nothing changed
- I tried to connect the "[Trunk](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/pike/admin/config-trunking.html)" option to Neutron and configure additional entities like "network trunk" and "subport" - nothing changed. I had a suspicion that this was all intended to set up communication between two VMs on different networks, and not many VMs on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this option has one limitation - it only works with Linuxbridge

A worked configuration for me:

```
vi /etc/neutron/neutron.conf
...
[DEFAULT]
vlan_transparent = true
...
 
vi /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini
...
[ml2]
type_drivers = flat,vlan,vxlan,gre
tenant_network_types = vxlan
mechanism_drivers = linuxbridge
...
 
vi /etc/neutron/plugin.ini
...
[ml2]
type_drivers = flat,vlan,vxlan,gre
mechanism_drivers = linuxbridge
...
```

And only then I was able to create a network with option "vlan_transparent", but not through the CLI, but through the API:

```
$ curl -s -X POST http://internal.mystack.net:9696/v2.0/networks -H "X-Auth-Token: <TOKEN>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"network": {"name": "test", "admin_state_up": true, "tenant_id": "56b0cfe82ef94b2b8a60c53d72921a8b", "vlan_transparent": true}}'
 
$ openstack network show test --debug
...
{"networks": [{"provider:physical_network": null, "ipv6_address_scope": null, "dns_domain": null, "revision_number": 4, "port_security_enabled": true, "provider:network_type": "vxlan", "id": "78af4991-1b50-4b8d-9299-3a5dfaf689a2", "router:external": false, "availability_zone_hints": [], "availability_zones": [], "ipv4_address_scope": null, "shared": false, "project_id": "56b0cfe82ef94b2b8a60c53d72921a8b", "status": "ACTIVE", "subnets": [], "private_dns_domain": "mcs.local.", "description": "", "tags": [], "updated_at": "2022-03-29T13:22:00Z", "provider:segmentation_id": 88, "name": "test", "admin_state_up": true, "tenant_id": "56b0cfe82ef94b2b8a60c53d72921a8b", "created_at": "2022-03-29T13:22:00Z", "mtu": 1400, "vlan_transparent": true}]}
```

That is, if you add any "openvswitch" or "l2population" to the configuration in the "mechanism_drivers", then all this will abruptly stop working

I didn't develop the experiment further. realized that it doesn't suit me